# Explain this syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

Can anyone tell me why this has a syntax error? I've run this exact code before and it worked perfectly. The line in **strong text** is where Python tells me the syntax error is. Thanks, everyone!

```
import random

count = 0
while count < 10:

    attackerLV = 20
    attackerST = 20
    attackerSK = 20
    baseAtkPwr = 20
    attackPWR = ((random.randint(85,100) * (baseAtkPwr + attackerLV + attackerST + attackerSK)) // 100

    **defenderLV = 20**
    defenderCON = 20 
    defenderSKa = 20
    baseDefPwr = 20
    defensePWR = (((random.randint(85,100)) * (baseDefPwr + defenderLV + defenderCON + defenderSKa)) // 4) // 100

    damage = attackPWR - defensePWR

    if damage <= 1:
        damage = 1

    print(str(attackPWR))
    print(str(defensePWR))
    print(str(damage))
    print()

    count = count + 1
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spotting a trivial syntax error.

Comment: Python shows where it thinks the error is with a little `^`. If that's not helpful, the best thing to do is to take your massive expression and break it up into separate sub-expressions on separate lines, storing the intermediate results in variables that you can substitute in to the main expression. Then it will become obvious where you went wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on valid statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472645/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-on-valid-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis here:

```
attackPWR = ((random.randint(85,100) * (baseAtkPwr + attackerLV + attackerST + attackerSK)) // 100
```